# MediaWiki with MariaDB on Docker

Tags: docker, mediawiki, mariadb

I have 2 containers with 2 different MediaWiki running and I want to know. Do I need to create 2 containers with 2 MariaDB or just 1 container with MariaDB and two different DB inside? What is the best?

Comment: Depends on what the scope of the two different MediaWikis are, and what level of separation is relevant from a backup/recovery standpoint.